# how to proxy to backend server on certain path?

Tags: react-router, webpack-dev-server

Here is the routes config:

```
<Route path='/' component={CoreLayout}>
  <IndexRoute component={HomeView}/>
  <Route path='/404' component={NotFoundView}/>
  <Redirect from='*' to='/404'/>
</Route>
```

Here is the proxy config for webpack-dev-server:

```
proxy: {
  '/service': 'http://localhost:8080'
}
```

The express server listens on 3000 port.

I hope that all the requests send to http://localhost:3000/service would be transferred to http://localhost:8080, but it seems that react-router handles all the requests and the proxy does not work.

Any body knows how to fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I am also having issues with this, does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check [Webpack Dev Server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) documentation, you need to provide object with *target* property.
2. [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching) documentation shows usage of *patterns* for matching.

In conclusion, I would try this:

```
proxy: {
  '/service/**': { target: 'http://localhost:8080' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are handling promises correctly for the API calls. I was facing the same issue, wherein the client server was handling all the of the API calls instead of returning a 404 error and proxy taking over.

```
fetch("/api/list")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      // handle the data
      })
```