# React routing and proxy- Routing not allowing proxy to catch

Tags: reactjs, webpack, proxy, server

I am having a very similar issue to what was noted here:
[how to proxy to backend server on certain path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888206/how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-on-certain-path)  but this answer does not solve the error.

My webpack-dev-server proxy is not catching because my route which catches all non specified routes:

path: '(.* )',
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'not-found' */ './not-found'),

is blocking the proxy route to my api.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.